Pandas concatenate is not keeping my columns. All of the data is being merged into one column
My problem is that I need to take multiple json responses from multiple requests and then concatenate these requests into one csv file. I use an outer join with pd.concat but instead of keeping the columns from the dataframe it puts everything into one singular column. Is there a way to fix this?
Here is my code:
data = []
full_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
uuid_counter = 0
for uuid in uuid_df['uuid']:
    headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'api-key': APIKEY}
    response = re.get(
        f'URL/{uuid}',
        headers=headers)
    json_response = response.json()
    df = pd.json_normalize(json_response)
    full_df = pd.concat([full_df, df])
    full_df.to_csv('research.csv')
    uuid_counter += 1


Have you tried printing the contents of df during you loop to make sure the json normalize is doing what you want it to?

Yeah df is formatted correctly. It keeps everything in the correct columns, but for some reason concatenating them removes the columns
